# Finding the limit of the sequence with $a_1=a$, $a_2=b$, and $a_{n}=\sqrt{a_{n-1} a_{n-2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let there be a recursive sequence that begins with two terms, $a_1 = a$ and $a_2 = b$. The third term, $a_3$, is created by taking the geometric mean ($\sqrt{a \times b}$) of the previous two terms. The fourth term, $a_4$, is once again created by taking the geometric mean of the previous two terms. This process is repeated indefinitely.

For example, if $a = 1$ and $b = 8$,

$a_3 = \sqrt{1 \times 8}=  \sqrt8 =2.82843... $

$a_4 = 4.75683...$

$a_5 = 3.66802...$

$a_6 = 4.17710...$

...and so on.

If you'll notice, as the terms go on, they are slowly converging towards one number. In this case, it's 4. This number will (tentatively) be called the "limit" ($L$).

My question is, what is the general rule for finding $L$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The recurrence relation is given by: $$a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1} \cdot a_n}$$ With initial conditions: $$a_1=a$$ And: $$a_2=b$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply recurrence formula:

$$ \begin{align}
a_{n+2} &= \sqrt{a_{n+1}\cdot a_n} \\
a_{n+2}^2 &= a_{n+1}\cdot a_n 
\end{align} 
$$

to compute explicitly:

$$ \begin{align}
a_3^2 &= a_2\cdot a_1, \quad \\
a_4^2 &= a_3\cdot a_2, \quad   \\
a_5^2 &= a_4\cdot a_3, \quad  \\ 
a_6^2 &= a_5\cdot a_4, \quad   \\
\ldots &= \ldots \\
a_n^2 &= a_{n-1}\cdot a_{n-2}, \quad    \\
a_{n+1}^2 &= a_n\cdot a_{n-1}, \quad   \\
a_{n+2}^2 &= a_{n+1}\cdot a_n. \quad  (1)  \\
\end{align}$$
Multiply sides by sides:
$$ a_3^2\cdot a_4^2\cdot a_5^2 \cdot a_6^2\ldots a_n^2\cdot a_{n+1}^2\cdot a_{n+2}^2 = a_1\cdot a_2^2 \cdot a_3^2\cdot a_4^2\ldots a_{n-1}^2\cdot a_n^2\cdot a_{n+1}$$

Simplify:

$$ a_{n+1}\cdot a_{n+2}^2 = a_1\cdot a_2^2, \quad \forall n \ge 0. \quad (2) $$

For convenience, let's define:

$$c^2 = a_1a_2^2. \quad (3) $$

Then $(2)$ becomes:

$$ a_{n+2} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}} = \frac{c}{a_{n+1}^{1/2}}. \quad(4)  $$

Apply $(4)$ to compute $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n$:
$$ \begin{align}
a_{n+2} &= \frac{c}{ a_{n+1}^{1/2}} 
         = \frac{c}{ c^{1/2}{a_n^{-1/4}}} \\
&= c^{1/2} a_n^{1/2^2}. \quad (5)
\end{align}
$$

Thus, we can evaluate $(5)$ repeatedly for odd indices:
$$ \begin{align}
a_3 &= c^{1/2} \left( a_1 \right)^{1/2^2} \\
a_5 &=  c^{1/2}\left( a_3 \right)^{1/2^2} =  c^{1/2} \left(  c^{1/2} a_1^{1/2^2} \right)^{1/2^n} = \left(c\right)^{2^{-1} + 2^{-3}} a_1^{2^{-4}} \\
a_7 &=  c^{1/2}\left( a_5 \right)^{1/2^2} =
 c^{1/2} \left(  c^{1/2} a_3^{1/2^2} \right)^{1/2^n} = \left(c\right)^{2^{-1} + 2^{-3} + 2^{-5}} a_1^{2^{-6}} \\
\ldots &= \ldots \\
a_{2n+1} &=  c^S a_1^{2^{-2n}}, \quad (6) 
\end{align}$$
where $S$ is the following geometric series:
$$ S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^5} \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$$ 
$$\implies S - \frac{1}{2^2}S = \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}  $$
$$ \implies\lim_{n\to\infty} S = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n+1} = c^{2/3} a_1^0 = \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2^2}. \quad (7)$$

Similarly, it can be shown that for even indices:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n+2} = c^{2/3} a_2^0 = \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2^2}. \quad (8)$$

Because both the odd and even sequences of $a_n$ are convergent to the same value, the sequence $a_n$ is convergent to the same value.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L = \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2^2}. \quad (9) $$

Thus, for the problem of interest, we have:

$$ L = \sqrt[3]{ab^2} = \sqrt[3]{1\cdot 8^2} = 4 $$

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation, thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Considering the first few terms: 
$$a, b, a^{\frac 12}b^{\frac 12}, a^{\frac 14}b^{\frac 34}, a^{\frac 38}b^{\frac 58}, $$
we see that the index of either $a$ or $b$ of each term is the arithmetic mean of the indices of the  $a$ or $b$ of the previous 2 terms.

We therefore can start by finding the limit of the recursive sequence of arithmetic means:
$$m, n, \frac 12(m+n), \frac 12(n+\frac 12(m+n)),...$$
We can find the arithmetic mean of the previous 2 terms simply by subtracting from the second term half the signed difference between them, taking second minus first.

Let $d = n - m$, the sequence can be written as follows:
$$m, n, n-\frac d2, n-\frac d2+\frac d4, n-\frac d2+\frac d4, n-\frac d2+\frac d4-\frac d8,...$$

Note that each new difference is half the previous difference in magnitude and the signs of these differences alternate.

And we can rewrite and compute the infinite series:
$$n-\frac d2+\frac d4-\frac d8+... = n-\Bigl(\frac d2+\Bigl(\frac d2\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac {-1}{2}\Bigr)+\Bigl(\frac d2\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac {-1}{2}\Bigr)^2+\Bigl(\frac d2\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac {-1}{2}\Bigr)^3+...\Bigr)$$
$$=n-\frac {\frac d2}{1+\frac 12}$$
$$=n-\frac d3$$
$$=n-\frac {n-m}{3}$$
$$=\frac {m+2n}{3}$$
Now substitute $m=1$ and $n=0$ to get $1/3$ for the index of $a$, and substitute $m=0$ and $n=1$ to get $2/3$ for the index of $b$.

Comment: Other methods to find the limit of a sequence in which each term is the arithmetic mean of the preceding 2 terms can be found in the answers to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276402/774987